# Io does not compile on Mac OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: 64-bit, io, cmake, compilation, libffi

I followed the instructions in the README, they are very simple

```
cd build
cmake ..
make install
```

The problem occurs after the make install command. Io will not compile, specifically because of the module CFFI. ld complains that my libffi.dylib is not 64-bit, and thus it won't link the .o files, and because of that, it then complains that this or that symbol is not defined, etc.

```
ld: warning: in /opt/local/lib/libffi.dylib, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
```

How can I solve this? Is there a way to compile Io in 32-bit, by passing parameters to make, cmake or editing some file? The Makefile has an entry for the CFFI addon. Could i just delete it? where can i get a 64-bit libcffi? this library provides an API to access lower-level function calls for higher level languages, so i+m not so sure about replacing my 32-bit one with 64-bit one, it may break my MacRuby or other stuff. i would like to be able to build it with the CFFI and all the possible addons that may work in my system, to be able to do more stuff: i am interested in the objective-c bindings, which i guess may require cffi.

Answer (score 1):

On the Mac, you can compile as 32-bit only by setting CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES = i386 in your CMake cache.

Run "cmake-gui ." in the build tree, and then change CMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES to i386. Then do a clean build. You should end up with 32-bit binaries at that point.

On other OSes (Linux, Windows) there are different techniques to get 32-bit builds on 64-bit systems. They involve either passing certain flags to the compiler (-m32 -m64 for gcc) or using the proper CMake generator (Visual Studio 9 2008 vs. Visual Studio 9 2008 Win64).